# "It is true statement" vs. "It is a true statement"

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

When there is a statement written, and we want to comment on it, which of the following is correct, and why?

> It is true statement.

or

> It is a true statement.

Comment: Hi Farhad, you may not realise that English Language & Usage (EL&U) is a question and answer site for *linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts*. For further information about what's expected in a question on our EL&U site, see [Ask]. For your reference, note that our other site [ell.se] offers a wealth of information that's useful for both native speakers and learners. This kind of question would be much more appropriate for that site. :-)

Answer (score 0):

'Statement' is a countable noun according to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/statement), so 'It is a true statement.' would be the right answer.